# What are the "name" and "type" attributes used for in Formik?

Tags: html, reactjs, formik

Currently following the Formik Tutorial and I'm curious what `name` and `type` attributes are used for? I couldn't find an answer to this in their documentation.

From my understanding, the `id` attribute is for linking `input` to the `label`. However, a type of "email" doesn't exist, and I'm unsure why giving the input a name of "email" does anything.

To me they seem like 2 unnecessary lines of code, but I'm sure they must be useful some how. What am I missing?

[image: Formik Tutorial]

Answer (score 1):

Formik uses the HTML input tags which have a type attribute to indicate to the browser what type of input is being requested, e.g. email for email fields to ensure only email addresses are inputted, i.e. email@emailaddress.com, or submit for submit buttons.  The name attribute is used to reference form elements, and data after it has been submitted.  It is also needed in order for data entered into that element to be passed when the form is submitted.

References:

FormikDocs. Overview. https://formik.org/docs/overview. (Accessed 13 February, 2021).

w3schools.com. HTML <input> tag. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp. (Accessed 13 February, 2021).

w3schools.com. HTML <input type="email">. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_email.asp. (Accessed 13 February, 2021).

w3schools.com. HTML <input> name Attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_input_name.asp. (Accessed 13 February, 2021).